# css3 webkit transform rotate not working

Tags: jquery, css, transform, rotatetransform

My signpost div is showing up in the DOM (after being appending with jquery) but the width and height dont seem to work with the webkit transforms in place. if i take the transforms out i can see my div. my aim is to append the div and then animate it in with rotation coming from -90deg to 0deg and a pivot point at the bottom of the div

my css:

```css
#signpost {
    background: url("../imgs/signpost.png");
    background-size:cover ;
    width:213px ;
    height:232px ;
    position:absolute;
    left:2em ;
    bottom:2em;
    z-index:999999 ;
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:80% 50% ;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces before your semicolons?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that's fine anyways.. -OP *after being appending with jquery* can we see your jQuery?

Comment: @Mr.Alien it doesn't cause any problems, it's just strange practice.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly We always get to see strange things here :D

Comment: And it's not consistent. Some of the semicolons do have spaces, some don't. Same with the spaces after the colons. Anyway, OP, you say animate, but I don't see any animation or transition properties. Also, do you know what an element with rotateY(90deg) looks like?

Comment: 1) No jQuery is needed for this 2) Please fiddle this in http://jsFiddle.net/ 3) @MrAlien and the others: :D

Comment: 4) why webkit only ? 5) @MrLister gave the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the lack of information, I for some reason assummed that applying rotate in css3 would animate for me, dont know where a got that notion from!

Ive got a job converting a questionaire built in flash to a CSS3/jQuery site because the company wants to make their product available on mobile. The one thing i was having trouble with is the rotating animation of the sign in the bottom left hand corner of the screen. I found a way to use a separate class to store the animation and add it when instructed.

jQuery

```
$("#signpost").animate({
    "left":48,
    "bottom":-16
});
$("#signpost").addClass("animaterotation");
```

CSS

```
#signpost {
    background: url("../imgs/signpost.png");
    background-size:cover ;
    width:213px ;
    height:232px ;
    position:absolute;
    left:-213px ;
    bottom:-4em ;
    z-index:999999 ;
    cursor:pointer ;
}
.animaterotation {
    -webkit-animation-name:             rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:         0.35s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
            transform-origin:0% 80%;
            -ms-transform-origin:0% 80%; /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform-origin:0% 80%; /* Safari and Chrome */

            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  to { 
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

here's a link to the original:

http://www.bigambition.co.uk/games/dream-job/

here's a link to what I've built:

http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00595392/dreamjobs/

Again,
Sorry for the bad communication,

Finbar

Answer (score 2):

@MrLister gave the solution, because since the question states:

> ... but the width and height dont seem to work with the webkit transforms in place. if i take the transforms out i can see my div

you are probably thinking you are using some other kind of transform.

An object rotated (Y or X) of 90 degree is not visible:

<kbd>[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYvqN/1/)</kbd>

Demo HTML

```
<div class="notRotated">not rotated</div>
<div class="rotated30">rotated(Y) 30 deg </div>
<div class="rotated60">rotated(Y) 60 deg </div>
<div class="rotated80">rotated(Y) 80 deg </div>
<div class="rotated90">rotated(Y) 90 deg </div>
```

Demo CSS

```
div{
    background : blue;
        height : 50px;
         width : 200px;
        margin : 20px;
         color : white;
}    
.rotated30{
    transform : rotateY(30deg);
}
.rotated60{
    transform : rotateY(60deg);
}
.rotated80{
    transform : rotateY(80deg);
}
.rotated90{
    transform : rotateY(90deg);
}
```

Comment: @enyce12 added to the answer, Nettuts+ Prefixr for the win

Comment: @enyce12 not updated, or not needed anymore (maybe due to runtime prefixers like Lea Verou's PrefixFree ) ? This sounds new to me...

Comment: I meant not needed anymore when using a preprocessor. I'm working with Sass and it became obsolete to me (since I'm using bourbon to do the vendor prefixing). Lea Verou's PrefixFree is another nice solution but it fails for the case you need to support disabled JavaScript.